# Convert strftime in SQLite request to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, strftime

I converted the SQLite line

```
WHERE strftime('%d%m', orders.created_at) = .......
```

directly to a MySQL monster:

```
WHERE CONCAT(CAST(DAY(orders.created_at) AS CHAR), LPAD(CAST(MONTH(orders.created_at) AS CHAR), 2, '0')) = .........
```

Please, help me to rewrite it to a shorter one.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[STRFTIME()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in SQLite is similar to [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in MySQL with reversed parameters.

Since `%d` and `%m` map to the same thing in both, your expression can simply be written as;

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(orders.created_at, '%d%m') = .......
```

Comment: When I do this, I get following error: DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'LeadListEntry.created' in 'field list'"). Here LeadListEntry is table name and created is datetime field?