# Django group by date with strftime in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, group-by

```
dic = {
    'year': 'strftime("%%Y", created_time)',
    'month': 'strftime("%%Y-%%m", created_time)',
    'day': 'strftime("%%Y-%%m-%%d", created_time)',
    'hour': 'strftime("%%Y-%%m-%%d-%%H", created_time)',
    'hour_total': 'strftime("%%H", created_time)',
}

all_posts = all_posts.extra({'date': dic[method]}).order_by().values('date') \
        .annotate(p_count=Count('created_time'))
```

I wanted to group by date, so I used that source in sqlite3.
I changed my database to PostgreSQL, and then that code doesn't work.
What do I do for this source?

I need to group year, month, day, hour(some date in hour) and hour(total date hour for statistics by time.).

> column "%Y-%m" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT MAX("p_count") FROM (SELECT (strftime("%Y-%m", area

This is my error and my django version is 1.8.5.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" entail? errors? invalid results? what version of django?

Comment: @Sayse, edit my question! I use django 1.8.5 and "column "%Y-%m" does not exist" is error

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you get this error because you use double quotes instead of single quotes (I mean that you need to write `'%%H'`, not `"%%H"`). But after that you'll definitely get another error:

> function strftime(unknown, timestamp with time zone) does not exist

So if you want to fix it, you can use [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) function instead of strftime.

**UPDATE:**

Since Django 1.10 you can use class [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) with `annotate` instead of `extra` (this method is marked as deprecated), and it doesn't depend on database that you use.

Comment: I am using Django==1.5.5 along with MySQL and am getting same error(function strftime does not exist) when doing extra. Is there any way to handle this in MySQL?

Comment: Sid, please look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361074/convert-strftime-in-sqlite-request-to-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't knew that sqlite and mysql behave differently for these function. Though even after doing this I am getting an error which I have mentioned in linked question comment. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Sid, please create a new question so you'll be able to describe your problem with more details.