# MySQL calculate Monthly Total excluding last record every month

Tags: mysql

I have data in below format:

```
Date                        Price
2019-10-09 12:18:00 11239.45
2019-10-10 11:15:00 11253.8
2019-10-11 09:24:00 11339.6
2019-10-11 10:39:00 11248.1
2019-10-15 13:27:00 11410
2019-10-23 09:30:00 11583.5
2019-10-29 09:24:00 11652.75
2019-10-31 15:00:00 11860.85
2019-11-04 11:06:00 12002.1
2019-11-04 12:06:00 11945.85
2019-11-05 14:39:00 11961.6
2019-11-08 13:36:00 11984.05
2019-11-11 15:18:00 11950
2019-11-13 14:48:00 11863.85
2019-11-14 11:06:00 11918.65
2019-11-14 12:24:00 11843.7
2019-11-14 15:03:00 11891.35
2019-11-18 09:33:00 11915
2019-11-19 11:33:00 11970.1
2019-11-20 14:24:00 12006
2019-11-25 11:33:00 12013.9
2019-11-28 15:32:00 12152
2019-11-28 15:33:00 12191
2019-11-28 15:33:00 12191
2019-11-29 11:00:00 12107
2019-12-04 14:36:00 12049.45
2019-12-05 14:39:00 12038.2
2019-12-11 15:06:00 11940
2019-12-23 14:27:00 12236.5
2019-12-23 15:09:00 12280.9
2019-12-24 15:21:00 12230.25
2019-12-27 09:15:00 12220.4
2019-12-30 12:18:00 12278.6
2019-12-30 15:00:00 12333.45
2019-12-31 10:48:00 12268.15
2020-01-02 09:30:00 12282
```

I want to get monthly sum of Price excluding last record of that month
E.G.

```
2019-10-09 to 2019-10-29  | Oct-19  | 79727
2019-10-31 to 2019-11-28  | Nov-19  | 203661
2019-11-29 to 2019-12-30  | Dec-19  | 121714
```

I had query for SQLite for calculating for one month but I want to query for all records not single month in MySQL (as migrated from SQLite to MySQL):

```
select strftime("%m-%Y", Time), sum(Price) from order_book
where  time >= (select max(Time) from order_book where strftime("%m-%Y", Time) = strftime("%m-%Y",date('now','start of month','-1 month')))
```

Comment: can you post the create table and sample data sql dump, or create it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: try `select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') as ym,sum(price) from YOUR_TABLE where date not in (select max(date) from YOUR_TABLE group by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')) group by ym;`

Comment: *I had query for SQLite for calculating for one month* Does `Date` column is set to UNIQUE? if not then the query is incorrect.

Comment: @BerndBuffen
CREATE TABLE `nf_daily_record` (
  `Date` text,
  `Price` double DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: @Akina The SQLite had Date column as unique

Comment: @BerndBuffen
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a082e1/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert strftime in SQLite request to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361074/convert-strftime-in-sqlite-request-to-mysql)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a new query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`date`),'%Y-%m-%d')
      , ' - '
      , DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`date`),'%Y-%m-%d')
     ) AS 'Date range'
      , DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`date`) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%b-%y') AS 'Month/Year'
   , FORMAT(SUM(price),2) AS 'total'
FROM (
SELECT 
   @rno := IF(`date`IN (
             SELECT max(`date`)
             FROM order_book 
             GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')),@rno+1,@rno) AS rno,
   ob.*
FROM order_book AS ob
JOIN (SELECT @rno := 0) AS init) AS withgroup
GROUP BY rno;
```

at first the inner query generates a group number and the outer only group all

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT(
    ->         DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`date`),'%Y-%m-%d')
    ->       , ' - '
    ->       , DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`date`),'%Y-%m-%d')
    ->      ) AS 'Date range'
    ->    , DATE_FORMAT(MAX(`date`),'%b-%y') AS 'Month/Year'
    ->    , FORMAT(SUM(price),2) AS 'total'
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT 
    ->    @rno := IF(`date`IN (
    ->              SELECT max(`date`)
    ->              FROM order_book 
    ->              GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')),@rno+1,@rno) AS rno,
    ->    ob.*
    -> FROM order_book AS ob
    -> JOIN (SELECT @rno := 0) AS init) AS withgroup
    -> GROUP BY rno;
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| Date range              | Month/Year | total      |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
| 2019-10-09 - 2019-10-29 | Oct-19     | 79,727.20  |
| 2019-10-31 - 2019-11-28 | Nov-19     | 203,661.00 |
| 2019-11-29 - 2019-12-30 | Dec-19     | 121,714.75 |
| 2019-12-31 - 2020-01-31 | Jan-20     | 159,237.10 |
| 2020-01-31 - 2020-02-19 | Feb-20     | 84,322.45  |
| 2020-02-20 - 2020-03-23 | Mar-20     | 95,928.95  |
| 2020-03-31 - 2020-04-23 | Apr-20     | 62,082.25  |
| 2020-04-27 - 2020-05-11 | May-20     | 55,513.90  |
| 2020-05-12 - 2020-05-12 | Jun-20     | 9,189.70   |
+-------------------------+------------+------------+
9 rows in set, 0 warnings (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b2d57/38

Comment: You have ignored the last date of the previous month as requirment  but not included the previously ignored date from the last month in the current month.

Comment: Thank you @BerndBuffen for sharing the details. as mentioned by Shyam it would be great if we add last date from previous month also

Comment: @ML-DL-Learner - i have change my answer with a new query

Comment: @hyam - pls upvote - i have change the anser